# COMO IMPRIMIR VALOR DEL NOMBRE DESDE UN DATAGRID A COMBOBOX WPF

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf, mvvm

tengo el sigueinte problema hasta el momento e logrado pasar de datagrid a textbox pero tengo un problema y es con el combo box lamentablemente cuando selecciono una fila de mi data grid puedo ver todos los campos que se encuentran con textbox pero el seleccionado del combo box no lo puedo visualizar quisiera una ayuda de como poder solventar ese problema a continuacion dejo los siguientes codigos que podrian ayudar para guiarme a una solucion

listar provinvia

```
public void ListarProvincia() {
        CN_Proveedores objCNPro = new CN_Proveedores();
        cmb_Provincia.ItemsSource = objCNPro.GetProvincias();
        this.cmb_Provincia.DisplayMemberPath = "Nombre";
        this.cmb_Provincia.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
    }
```

seleccion de fila del datagrid y paso de datos a textbox

```
 private void dgvProveedores_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (dgvProveedores.SelectedItem != null)
        {

            DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
            DataRowView rowView = dataGrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
            try
            {
                if (rowView.Row != null)
                {
                    string dt1 = rowView.Row[1].ToString(); /* 1st Column on selected Row */
                    string dt2 = rowView.Row[2].ToString();
                    string idProvincia = rowView.Row[3].ToString();
                    string dt4 = rowView.Row[4].ToString();
                    string dt5 = rowView.Row[5].ToString();
                    string dt6 = rowView.Row[6].ToString();

                    string dto = rowView.Row[0].ToString();
                    TXT_Nombre_Proveedor_P.Text = dt1;
                    TXT_RUC.Text = dt2;
                    cmb_Provincia.ItemsSource = objetoCN.GetProvincias();
                    cmb_Provincia.DisplayMemberPath ="Nombre";
                    cmb_Provincia.SelectedValuePath = idProvincia;
                    TXT_Ciudad.Text = dt4;
                    TXT_direccion.Text = dt5;
                    TXT_Telefono.Text = dt6;

                    idProveedor = dto;
                }
                else if(rowView.Row == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Debe contener informacion");

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No puede seleccionar un campo vacio");


            }

        }
        else
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Selecciones una fila");
        }
    }
```

a continuacion dejo capturas de la ejecucion y del como al momento de seleccionar una fila se seleccionan los valores para los texbox pero para el combobox el valor predeterminado por el id no contiene un valor asignado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para el caso de idProvincia 6 me deberia retornar el nombre de esa respectiva provincia al combobox ya que el id se guarda en mi tabla de sql mediante el selectedvaluepath de listarProvincia lo que quisiera q me salga seria de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y otra cuestion es que al momento de seleccionar una fila vacia me salta la siguiente exepción cual seria un camino para solventar ese problema a partir de un messagebox

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hola estás realmente utilizando MVVM?